# Are there distros that still ship GTK+ 1?

Tags: gtk

GTK+ 1 has been deprecated some years ago, and I'm curious if there's still anyone shipping it and/or apps using it. Also, are there still actively-developed apps using it?

Answer (score 4):

Current Fedora 15 includes gtk+ 1.2.10. The package release is "71" — looks like it's gone through a lot.

What uses it? In Fedora rawhide:

```
bubblemon (displays CPU load and memory as a bubbling jar of water)
crossfire-client (multiplayer roguelike)
dillo (minimal GUI web browser)
gcombust (cd recording front end)
gcx (ccd photometry data reduction tool)
gnome-libs (yeah, gnome 1. Apparently also still shipping.)
gsview (gui for ghostscript)
libglade (which doesn't seem to be used for anything)
manedit ("integrated XML interface" for man page editing. why? why?)
siril (astronomical image processing software)
soundtracker (tracker, as in synth music)
spacechart (3d stars)
swami (midi instrument editor)
xarchon (ancient clone of the classic game)
xconvers (ever wondered what port 3600 was for?)
xdialog (this once was the cutting edge of user-interaction design)
xmms (and many xmms plugins and sub-packages)
```

File that under "huh, lookit that". :)

None of these apps appear to be actively developed — those that are, like dillo, have newer versions that use different toolkits. I can't imagine why an app that was actively worked on wouldn't have migrated by now.

Comment: *I can't imagine why an app that was actively worked on wouldn't have migrated by now.* ...because it's actively worked on? (By old dogs that don't want to learn new tricks?)

Comment: @AloisMahdal Well, maybe in theory. But we don't have any examples of that.

Comment: sure, *fortunately* we don't have many examples. In theory, project activity could be part of the reason why it's hard to migrate. Yes, well-managed and versioned projects with healthy morale do not tend to have this problem, but I have seen projects where the above (rather ironic) remark would describe the reason quite accurately. (Other factors such as major changes in the backend being seen as controversial by part of the contributing community may have influence.)

Answer (score 2):

RHEL4 (and CentOS4) still ships gtk+-1.2 packages.  It looks like their gnome-libs package uses it.

Answer (score 2):

ArchLinux still allows you to install GTK1. The [package page](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gtk/) also lists a few apps depending on it.

Answer (score 2):

Slackware ships with gtk1.2. Currently (13.1) ships gtk+ 1.2.10 (as well as gtk-2 of course). I believe debian/ubuntu has legacy packages for it too (but they're not installed by default)

I don't think newer stuff uses it, but a lot of already-existing, good (perhaps even maintained) software uses it.

I see it from a computer power perspective. gtk-2 and the software written for it, like many newer things have a lot more candy and convenience built in, with negligible performance loss on a modern system. Step back ten years though and you can tell a sharp difference in performance, where the gtk-1.2 equivalent software runs smoothly.